# Showing a message (perhaps using a redirect) after a Fileds form is submitted in Drupal 7

Tags: entities, rules

I am using Drupal 7 + Rules. I have this form (creates a new node of some content type , dunno the correct jargon here) that users can fill to apply for a job. I want to show them a static message after the form submission. Apparently Rules is the way to go. How to do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup Rules to display a message when ever a node of the specific type is created. There is an interface for creating Rules you want

Event: Creating a new node
Condition: The node is of the chosen type
Action: Display a message

Alternatively you can use code with `hook_form_alter`, and add a submit handler to the node submit of the specific type, where you use `drupal_set_message` to display the message. This can be done faster (if you know how to create modules for drupal, and it requires less resources (is faster in execution) than the Rules solution.